# Let $p, q$ be odd primes. Find the largest integer $n$ such that there exists an integer $a$ with $\gcd(a, pq) = 1$ with order equal to $n \bmod pq$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the largest integer $n$ here? I'm not sure how to start it. Thank you very much!

Comment: In other words, the largest order of an element of the (not necessarily cyclic) group $(\mathbb Z/pq\mathbb Z)^\times$

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that $p\ne q$). We have $a^n\equiv 1\pmod{pq}$ if and only if $a^n\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $a^n\equiv1\pmod q$. In other words, the order of $a$ modolo $pq$ is the lcm of the orders modulo $p$ and modulo $q$. The multiplicative groups modulo a prime are cyclic, hence there exists $a_p$ of order $p-1$ modulo $p$. Similarly there exists $a_q$ of order $q-1$ modulo $q$ (and for all other elements, the order divides $p-1$ resp. $q-1$). By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we find $a$ with $a\equiv a_p\pmod p$ and $a\equiv a_q\pmod q$. Then $a$ has order $$\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$$ and this is the maximum possible.